# How to hold information for specific inputs

Tags: c++, arrays, input

What I want to do is to save time. For example say that you have array A. 3 inputs are given. "4,1000,5". You will search for the number "5" in between the indexes 4 and 1000 of A. Let's say that there is no "5" in this space and you want to hold this information. So that in an another search when you have to search for 5 in between some smaller number than 4, say 2, and some larger number than 1000, say 2000, you will not search for it in the previous space. Search time will be reduced.

I generalized the question, I'm not looking for an example which is only valid for this specific example.(you can say though)

Comment: How much "history" would you want to preserve?  Sounds a bit like pre-mature optimization to me.

Comment: @Chad for all inputs if  possible.

Comment: You will have a nice logical challenge when the ranges do not include each other. i. e. "6,1000,5", "0,1,5", "3,5,5", "2000,3000,5".

Comment: @Nacho maybe next input is "0,10,5" who knows? :)
at some point they will include eachother. If they don't then there is no problem in the first place.

Comment: Exactly, as LukeG said in his answer "the cache you are building up with this technique can get out of hand pretty quickly and could ... get even bigger than the array itself, eliminating the possible speed gain"

Answer (score 2):

You could do it exactly as you described. Create a datatype consisting of the information of your search (from-index, to-index, searched number) as well as the result (unsuccessful, or the found index). For every search you save this information in a list. When a new search is started you could first check if there is something relevant in the cache. If there is, you can limit the search space.

However, do mind that the cache you are building up with this technique can get out of hand pretty quickly and could (if there are a lot of searches done) get even bigger than the array itself, eliminating the possible speed gain. I don't think that's a viable way to optimize array searches. This would efficiently work only in very specific cases and I would probably not recommend doing this as a general optimization.